# Find some text in li text

Tags: jquery, html

I want to check if some text is available in an `li` list or not. If it is not available, alert `true` one time.

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="ioptionlist">
    <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```

For example, if I have an `"aa"` value text in this `li` list, alert `true`.

Comment: Make it clear.. I don't understand what does available text mean? probabbly empty li element?

Comment: Nop There are aa, bb, cc etc in my above example. Those are available text values. Therefor I want to check some text value have in this available text list. Example if check aa value, it is available in li list. So return alert true.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function inList(list, searchText) {
  return !!list.filter(function(index, item) {
    return $(item).text() === searchText;
  }).text();
}
var list = $('ul.ioptionlist > li');
alert(inList(list, 'c')); // shows "false"
alert(inList(list, 'cc')); // shows "true"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ioptionlist">
    <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#search").on('keyup', function() {
  searchInList($(this).val());
});

function searchInList(enteredVal) {
  $(".ioptionlist li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == enteredVal) {
      console.log(enteredVal + ' is available');
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='search' />
<ul class="ioptionlist">
  <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
  <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you please tell me if it is not available alert true one time only.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "one time only"? Above code would output only when the text matches.

Comment: If it is have two aa values it is return two available msg.

Comment: So you want first available match to be returned??

Comment: I want to return only one if it have one aa or more than one aa.

Comment: Ok. Code has been updated. Just add `return false` inside the condition and it would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an element by its text by using plain javascript and `document.evaluate`, using a xpath expression. You can either check for an exact match, or if the `li` contains the text:

```js
let e = document.evaluate("//li[text()='aa']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
let first = e.iterateNext();
console.log(first.textContent);  


let e1 = document.evaluate("//li[contains(., 'a')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
let first1 = e1.iterateNext();
console.log(first1.textContent);
```

```html
<ul class="ioptionlist">
    <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```

To simply check if the element with the given text exists:

```js
let e = document.evaluate("//li[text()='aa']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
let first = e.iterateNext();
console.log("element exists: " + !! first );
```

```html
<ul class="ioptionlist">
    <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Consider using `const` instead of `let`, since the values of `e` and `first` never change.